# How to pass optional parameters while accessing web service API in play framework?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, playframework-2.6

I am new to play framework and trying to integrate a microservice. I am using WSClient to call a web service. In order to call a POST rest API, I am passing request body which contains some required parameters and some optional. My question is how to pass Optional parameters here?

My Code sample is

```scala
def add = Action.async { implicit request =>
    UserDataForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      profileForm => {
        val response = profileForm.errorsAsJson
        Future(BadRequest(response).as("application/json"))
      },
      userData => try {
        ws.url("http://localhost:9000/" + "api/profile")
          .post(
            Map("userId" -> userData.userId, "firstName" -> userData.firstName, "lastName" -> userData.lastName, "country" -> userData.country, "address" -> userData.address)).map { response =>

          OutputWithErrors(response.body, response.status)
        }
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          Future(BadRequest(Message(false, e.getMessage).toJson.prettyPrint).as("application/json"))
      })
  }
```

So here `address` is optional parameter.

And form data i.e. `userData` here

```scala
case class UserForm(userId: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, country: String, address: Option[String])
  val UserDataForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "userId" -> nonEmptyText,
      "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "country" -> nonEmptyText,
      "address" -> optional(text)
    )(UserForm.apply)(UserForm.unapply)
  )
```

So while calling rest service API near `ws.url(...)post(Map("userId" -> userData, ...))` compiler is complaining about `No implicits found for parameter evidence$2: BodyWritable[Map[String, Serializable]]`

Comment: It's probably the adress parameter. Try to do a getOrElse("") for now and see if that compiles.

Comment: In addition to my answer, I think the try..catch is unnecessary, since Post won't throw an exception, but the Future might fail, which wouldn't be handled here. Try `recover` on the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the `Map` you are passing to `post`. All but one entry is `(String, String)`, but the last one is `(String, Option[String])`.

The compiler now has to figure out what the type of this collection might be and goes up the type hierarchy. The best type it can figure out is `Map[String, Serializable]`. Because that's the narrowest super type String and Option implement.

This is the definition for post:

`def post[T: BodyWritable](body: T): Future[Response]`

You can see there's a type constraint on T, which means that you need an implicit converter* for the body that is passed to post to `BodyWritable`. You can find the implicit BodyWritables in [DefaultBodyWritables](https://github.com/playframework/play-ws/blob/master/play-ws-standalone/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/DefaultBodyWritables.scala). And there is no `BodyWritable[Map[String, Serializable]]`. But there is one for `Map[String, String]`

You have to choices:

1. Change the Map so it has the type of `Map[String, String]`, either by providing a default value for `address` via `getOrElse` or don't add address to the map if it's None.
2. Write a BodyWritable for Map[String, Serializable]. (Which might not be possible in a satisfying way)

I suggest you go with #1.

* please correct me if that's not the right term for these kind of implicits.

Comment: Yes #1 option will do the job.. Thanks!